# Pandas datetime freq when date is offset from start of the month

Tags: pandas, datetime, frequency

I need to create a DatetimeIndex starting on a specific date and its day of the month, and then continuing on the same day of the month for subsequent months.
here's what I have:

```
import datetime
init_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10)
dates = pd.date_range(start=init_date, periods=10, freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(days=init_date.day - 1)
```

However, now dates.freq is None.
If I try to set it manually:

```
dates.freq = "M"
ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency M
```

There is no pandas freq for monthly frequency that is not on the first or last of the month. However, I need the freq down the line, and it would make sense to call it 'M'. is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If need `freq=M` it means need last days of months, so in your range is not possible set freq to `M` without change datetimes:

```
#freq is changed to `M`, but datetimes are changed
print (dates.to_series().asfreq('M'))
2018-02-28   NaT
2018-03-31   NaT
2018-04-30   NaT
2018-05-31   NaT
2018-06-30   NaT
2018-07-31   NaT
2018-08-31   NaT
2018-09-30   NaT
2018-10-31   NaT
Freq: M, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (dates.to_series().asfreq('M').index)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31',
               '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30',
               '2018-10-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Comment: That's exactly my question... how do I get it to have freq that is not None (can be M or any variation on it), when its not the last day of the month? if its on the 10th of each month its still a frequency of one month...

Comment: @Oren Matar I think not possible.